# What pattern exists in $ 80:730::x:344 $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was recently asked the following question by someone in my class:

> Choose the option that best completes the comparision:
>
> $$ 80:730::x:344 $$

and the choices given are:

- $48$ **(`*`)**
- $70$
- $40$
- $52$

Where $48$ is given to be the correct choice. I have no idea as to how the pattern is even interpreted. By general ratio-proportion checks, it should be: $ x = \frac{80*344}{730} \approx 37.70 $.

This was from an online test. Here's a screenshot he sent me:

[image: img]

Comment: I would guess $48$ is a typo for $38$, but that is a wild guess.

Comment: I'd venture to say the same as @Ross, otherwise, the proportion symbol has been hijacked to mean something other than its conventional meaning.

Comment: If you mean the double-colon, that's pretty commonly used, but not in mathematics (if this is from a standardized test, it probably got carried over from its use in word analogies).  Since the "48" got marked as "correct", I agree that it's a typo.  Unfortunately, a nasty trick they like to use in some standardized tests is that 40 is the closest to 38, so that is the "option that best completes the comparison"; so I wouldn't have been surprised to see the third choice given as "correct".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For problems like this reasons for each answer can be easily found.

The answer he probably had in mind is based on the observation that $81, 729, 49, 343$ are $9^2, 9^3, 7^2, 7^3$. Your numbers are obtained by alternately subtracting/adding one.

But in reality all four answers are right (or wrong).

**P.S.** A joke answer is that " it is the best answer because those are the first four values produced by $385x^3-2976x^2+6883x-4212$".